# How to search through multiple set of dataset for columns and values in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

**jason data:** `avail":["Sun-2","Mon-2","Sun-3"]`

```
$avail = $data['avail'];
```

//Below I'm categorizing values by morning, afternoon and evening.

```
if($avail != ""){
        foreach($avail as $k=>$v)
        {
             $v;
           //dividing value before and after the symbol '-'
            $array = explode('-', $v);
            $day =$array[0]; // Wed
            $column =  $array[1]; // 2

            if($column == 1)
            {
            $col = "morning";

            }
            if($column == 2)
            {
                $col = "afternoon";
            }
            if($column == 3)
            {
                $col = "evening";
            }
            array_push($cols,$col);
            array_push($days,$day);
        }
```

Result for var_dump($cols);

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'afternoon' (length=9)
  1 => string 'afternoon' (length=9)
  2 => string 'evening' (length=7)
```

Result for var_dump($days);

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
  1 => string 'Mon' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
```

Now I query the table in the database like this:
//part of the query

```
$add_here .= sprintf(" AND %s",implode(' OR ', array_map(function($colx) use ($days) {return sprintf("posts.%s IN ('%s')", $colx, implode("','",$days));}, is_array($cols) ? $cols : array($cols))));
```

BUT only now, I've realized that I'm doing it the wrong way because the way I categorized the data made two arrays. One for session of the day and the other is dataset for each session altogether.

```
$days = ['sun','mon','tue']; <- data for morning,afternoon and evening mixed together
$col = ['afternoon','morning','evening'];
```

SO in the browser:

```
AND (posts.afternoon IN ('sun','mon','tue') OR posts.morning IN ('sun','mon','tue') OR posts.night IN ('sun','mon','tue'))
```

See that its checking all data for `$days` against each value of `$cols`. But what I want is, data for morning to check against morning column in the table while afternoon data to check against afternoon column in the table. Same goes for evening.

How do I change my code so that query would be like the following for the JSON dataset?

**jason data:** `avail":["Sun-2","Mon-2","Sun-3"]`

```
AND (posts.afternoon IN ('sun','mon') OR posts.night IN ('sun'))
```

> values for morning, afternoon and evening stored as a comma separated
>   values in the database. morning, afternoon and evening are column names in a table named posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the days by columns in an array first.

```
/* $periods[$column] = [$day1, ...] */
$periods = [];
foreach($avail as $v){
    list($day, $column) = explode("-", $v); // make sure you validated the data to avoid errors
    $periods[$column][] = "'" . mysqli_escape_string(strtolower($day)) . "'"; // PHP would automatically create an empty array if $periods[$column] was not defined
}
$intToCol = [1 => "morning", 2 => "afternoon", 3 => "night"];

// $periods should now be identical to ["2" => ["'sun'", "'mon'"], "3" => ["'sun'"]]

$conditions = [];
foreach($periods as $int => $days){
    $dayString = implode(",", $days);
    $conditions[] = "posts." . $intToCol[$int] . " IN ($dayString)";
}
return "AND (" . implode(" OR ", $conditions) . ")";
```

Comment: thanks seems like you get what I wanted. However I'm not sure how to apply the arrays in my query. Also what does return "AND (" . implode(" OR ", $conditions) . ")"; do?

Comment: var_dump($periods); returns empty string  and error : Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: I saw that you are using MySQL for the queries. I am not sure which MySQL wrapper you are using there, just putting that function to remind you to prevent SQL injections. If you think it is not necessary, just remove that function call.

Answer (score 0):

Let you guided by the result you're wanting: reading the query you need an array of OR'ed day-part conditions, each stating a list of week-days.

So you can work like this (tested, works fine):

```
$avail = ["Sun-2","Mon-2","Sun-3"];

$day_parts = [
  'morning',
  'afternoon',
  'evening',
];
$decoded = [];
if ($avail) {
  foreach ($avail as $v) {
    //dividing value before and after the symbol '-'
    $array = explode('-', $v);
    // register week_day as a key rather than a value, avoiding duplicates:
    $decoded[$day_parts[$array[1] - 1]]['"' . $array[0] . '"'] = TRUE;
  }
}

$ors = [];
foreach ($decoded as $day_part => $week_days) {
  if ($week_days) {
    $ors[] = 'posts.' . $day_part . ' IN (' . implode(',', array_keys($week_days)) . ')';
  }
}
if ($ors) {
  $where_part = ' AND (' . implode(' OR ', $ors) . ')';
}
```